# Upgrading to django 1.11 many to many column not found

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, django-migrations

I'm upgrading a project from Django 1.10.8 to 1.11 and am suddenly getting weird bugs in my unit tests.

I've used a slight hack to update an existing many-to-many relation to use a custom 'through' table with an extra 'order' field. All worked fine in 1.10 but now fails in 1.11 with

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column api_session_pollgroups.pollgroup_id does not exist
```

My model code looks like this:

```py
class SessionPollGroup(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey('api.Session')
    pollgroup = models.ForeignKey('api.PollGroup')
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'api_session_pollgroups'
        ordering = ('order',)
```

the table 'api_session_pollgroups' was preexisting when the initial many-to-many relation was made and I 'hijacked it' to add the extra order field.

relation on the session model looks like this

```py
    pollgroups = models.ManyToManyField('api.PollGroup',
                                        related_name='sessions',
                                        through=SessionPollGroup)
```

Anyone know why this would fail to either generate or find the correct db schema in django 1.11 and not 1.10 ?

Note: this seems to only appear during unit tests, when i create a new database using regular migrations the tables appear to be created correctly in my development db ( postgres ) but not in the unit test db ( sqlite )

thanks!

EDIT: Have scanned through the changelogs and cant see anything about this. Best I can come up with is something to do with tablespaces but I'm stumped as to what exactly.

Comment: Have you tried running `makemigrations`?

Comment: yeah nothing comes up :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was in fact to do with a (much) earlier rename of the model concerned. The django ticket linked below describes the issue well:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29000

An earlier migration that renamed the model was not properly resolved in django 1.11 ( this has changed from 1.10 ) and the relevant Foreign Key column names were not updated after the table rename. The polyfill migration operation class detailed in the ticket fixed the issue for me.